# C# - receiving a file through network stream is blocking WPF UI

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, task

I have this method for receiving a file.

```cs
public Task Download(IProgress<int> downloadProgress)
{
    return Task.Run
    (
        async () =>
        {
            var counter = 0;

            var buffer = new byte[1024];

            while (true)
            {
                var byteCount = await _networkStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                counter += byteCount;
                downloadProgress.Report(counter);

                if (byteCount != buffer.Length)
                    break;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Then in the UI I call it like this:

```cs
await Download(progress);
```

where progress is simply updating a label.

When I run, the UI will be blocked (but after some time it will correctly update the label). I don't understand why, shouldn't Task.Run() create a new thread?

How do I fix this please?

Comment: What (else?) is in the StartDownloading method? Also, have you tried using ConfigureAwait(false) on your 'await' calls?  I've found [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) helpful at times when dealing with async code

Comment: When you use `await`, you don‘t have to wonder that the UI thread is blocked. It does exactly what it says: it a*wait*s the result of the operation.

Comment: @GreggL StartDownloading is actually Download method, I edited my post

Comment: @PatrikBak, to clarify; when you say the UI is being blocked do you mean the application is actually entering a `Not Responding` state or that the progress label is not updating the way you anticipate?

Comment: @Sefe Are you not actually aware of the complexities of what `await` does, in how it restructures the method such that it executes the code following the `await` as a continuation to the awaited task, or do you just really think that those semantics are all conveyed in the word "await", because, I don't think they are, personally.  I don't think that someone who isn't familiar with the feature would realize that awaiting a task doesn't block the thread just from that one word alone.

Comment: @JSteward It means that nothing is updating, the windows can't be moved, all is just frozen. But it will unfreeze

Comment: @Servy, maybe you explain the complexities, because state machines and cooperative multitasking simply doesn't matter in this case, since using await in this context means blocking the UI thread.

Comment: @Sefe No, it doesn't.  `await` is *asynchronous*.  It doesn't synchronously block.  It was literally designed for *exactly* this situation; to make doing asynchronous work that doesn't block the UI thread easier to write an to have it *look* more like synchronous code (while still being asynchronous).  Feel free to look at an intro to async/await if you want to understand more about what it does and how it works, I can't really go into more detail that I did in these few comments in a comment thread like this.

Comment: May be you are reporting progress to frequently

Comment: @tabby You were right. The async/await/Task parts were correct...I have when the bug is exactly where I'm not looking ...Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `downloadProgress.Report` on an infinite loop without any pause in execution. My educated guess is this means every time execution time is available on the UI thread, the non-UI thread is requesting an operation which will require the UI thread's time (as demanded by the synchronisation context) and therefore clogging it up with invocations.

Essentially, rather than blocking the UI thread with one long execution, you may be blocking it with an un-ending stream of tiny ones.

Try putting a `Thread.Sleep(10)` in your 'spinlock' `while(true) { ... }` loop and see if that alleviates the issue.